# What happened to my coins, balance account is zero ... hacked?

Tags: transactions, wallet, address, hack

Yesterday I was surprised to seen that my wallet drop to zero by this transaction id : 504ebc5aa9c6dcdbfadfd97ccd47a289a309d829530e529e558b715563c4ec3b
It seems the adress : bc1q8yl5pq7p0cg6dtd85lz3hznj30rhe8k2s5kxhm
has picked all my BTC, plus others small transaction from somebody else are also availlable
Right now the transaction has been 36 times confirmed
and my balance show zero BTC.
Seems to be hacked ?
Did someone can help as I'm a newbie
Thx

Comment: What wallet/software/site are you using? Does your wallet still claim you have a balance?

Answer (score 1):

7,5 hours ago your funds were moved in transaction d25efe9d5f1f2cc1fc253e4b32631fdb99870fb29b34d06fb48f43fb0de7ae92 to address 13fgTXgdyNVrq9qUxrkGzjoBVjQVZ9nKx4 which belongs very likely to bittrex.com . So the exchange might have information about the sender.

I'd report it to both the exchange and the police a.s.a.p.

Answer (score 0):

> **Seems to be hacked?**

If you are *certain* you did not make this transfer, then yes, it is very likely that you have been "hacked" in some way.

> **What happened to my coins**

There is not enough information in the public blockchain to easily tell for certain. The recipient has not yet spent the money.

---

This is the sort of transaction that might occur if you were playing around with some new wallet software and tried out the "sweep key" function. If so, the money is in your new wallet not in the old.

It is also something that might happen if you had installed some software recently from a person or website you don't really know much about. In which case you might have installed some malware that, as well as doing what it promised, also installed some malicious features such as

- a "backdoor" that gives a criminal access to your device.
- a "keylogger" that captures the password to your wallet when you later use it.
- something that searches for passwords, private-keys, recovery-phrases, wallet files etc and sends them to a criminal.

In any case, if the bc1q8yl5pq7p0cg6dtd85lz3hznj30rhe8k2s5kxhm address is not known to any wallet software you are using, it means that money has been stolen and it is almost certain you will not recover it. At the moment it doesn't seem you have enough evidence of a crime to report anything to your local police.